# Multisite application gateway with different VNET

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, vnet

I have 2 resource group with different vnet but same address type, Can i create a common application gateway on either of the resource group with out VNET peering?
(I am using private endpoints for app services, I need to create single application gateway for both the resource groups with out vnet peering)

Comment: As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq#does-application-gateway-support-virtual-network-peering) its 'yes'

Comment: How ? I have two rg with different VNETs both are of same address type.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say no.it's possible with vnet peering but if you have same address type, it can't be peered.

Comment: There is a new feature(preview) that looks what you need. Can check this [Private link support in Azure Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/private-link-configure?tabs=portal)

Comment: Hi @JINUJANAN, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce with my environment but I found some issues. They are as below: -**

a) In application gateway we **can** surely connect with resources, i.e., **App services, VMs, VMSS in different resource groups and different VNets but they should all have a public IP address or a publicly accessible FQDN (endpoint)**.

b) Also, in an application gateway, we can **add resources with private endpoints in the backend pool but they should be in the same resource group as the application gateway**.

Please find the below snapshots for more clarification: -

***Application gateway --> Frontends***

[image: Application Gateway frontends]

In the front end pool, application gateway supports only one public or one private IP address

***Backend pool***

[image: Backend pool]

In the backend pool, the target IP address allows only **private ip address** in current resource group or **public endpoints** for app service in the any other resource group.

**Reference: -**

1. [Application Gateway integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/app-gateway-with-service-endpoints)
2. [Frequently asked questions about Azure Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq)